# Ansi C patch using dlsym compiles OK under linux but fails on Mac Os X

Tags: c++, c, macos, code-injection, dlsym

I have build a little patch to append to a certain application and trace the invocations of some functions. Among them, malloc() and open(). I am using dlsym to store the pointer to the original symbol and replace the function name with my own. It compiles -and works- perfectly under linux. Here's the code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

/**
 * Interponemos nuestra funcion open
 * 
 * @param   char*    filename
 * @param   int      flags
 **/

int open(char * filename, int flags)
{
    static int (*real_open)(char*, int) = NULL;
    if (!real_open)
        real_open = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");

    // Entero
    int p = real_open(filename, flags);
    fprintf(stderr, "Abrimos %s) = %i\n", filename, flags);

    // Devolvemos
    return p;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Interponemos nuestra funcion malloc
 * 
 * @param   size_t    size
 */

void* malloc(size_t size)
{
    static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;
    if (!real_malloc)
        real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");

    void *p = real_malloc(size);

    // Memoria reservada
    fprintf(stderr, "Reserva de memoria (%d) = %p\n", size, p);

    // Devolvemos
    return p;
}
```

Then, I compile it with the following instruction, creating a pi.so.

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -fPIC -shared -ldl -o pi.so pi.c
```

And then, I use the LD_PRELOAD directive to inject it into any app.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/home/.../injection/pi.so <binary>
```

And it worjks marvellous under Linux! But when I get back home and try to compile it using GCC under Mac, it fails to compile and the LD_PRELOAd directive does not work. What should I change? Thank you very much.

Comment: Just so you know, there was a technical corrigendum published to work around the fact that C does not define behaviour for converting a void pointer to a function pointer. See the example on the POSIX page for [dlsym](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) to see how to use it in a compliant manner.

Answer (score 4):

On mach, you have to use `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` macro instead of `LD_PRELOAD` to specify a list of shared libraries to pre-load (1...*).

By default, standard functions are not getting replaced with functions from the shared objects just because they have the same names. You have to explicitly state what function overrides what using [DYLD_INTERPOSE](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-132.13/include/mach-o/dyld-interposing.h) macro. It allows you to declare a replacement function with any name (for example, override `open` with `my_open`) and be able to call original function you are overriding. In addition to that, you don't have to resolve addresses of real functions manually.

Alternatively, to achieve Linux-like behavior you have to define `DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE` macro.

There is a lot more going on, see [dyld](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/dyld/) manual for details.

So your code should look something like this:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <mach-o/dyld-interposing.h>

/**
 * Interponemos nuestra funcion open
 * 
 * @param   char*    filename
 * @param   int      flags
 **/

int my_open(char * filename, int flags)
{
    // Entero
    int p = open(filename, flags);
    fprintf(stderr, "Abrimos %s) = %i\n", filename, flags);

    // Devolvemos
    return p;
}
DYLD_INTERPOSE(my_open, open)

//--------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Interponemos nuestra funcion malloc
 * 
 * @param   size_t    size
 */

void* my_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p = malloc(size);

    // Memoria reservada
    fprintf(stderr, "Reserva de memoria (%d) = %p\n", size, p);

    // Devolvemos
    return p;
}
DYLD_INTERPOSE(my_malloc, malloc)
```

Comment: I got it working :-) Thank you very much!! Dyld is also useful for class interposing? :)

Comment: @flaab You are welcome. This probably won't be useful for classes due to name mangling (depending on class name, namespace etcetera). Technically it is possible to override a class's method but that would be near impossible to support as name mangling is not standardized.

Comment: Hello Vlad :) I have managed to replace functions no problem. what I really need now is overriding a specific function of a class.

Comment: The especific function is QString::append(..., ..., ...). And the constructor would be ideal to override as well: all those would give me exactly the information i need :P

Comment: @flaab: In short, you better don't do it. Otherwise see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling and approach that method as a regular function. Maybe you will get some results, but I doubt that will work.

Comment: The header `mach-o/dyld-interposing.h` doesn't exist any more in the current macOS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The Mac OS X (10.6.4) does not contain any references to LD_PRELOAD - so it is ignored, and hence your attempt to interpose your code fails.  All the world is not the same as Linux.

Looking through the man pages, I found:

```
$ man dyld
```

...

> DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES
>       This is a colon separated list of dynamic libraries to load before the ones specified  in  the
>                 program.  This lets you test new modules of existing dynamic shared libraries that are used in
>                 flat-namespace images by loading a temporary dynamic shared library with just the new modules.
>                 Note  that  this  has  no  effect on images built a two-level namespace images using a dynamic
>                 shared library unless DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE is also used.

Answer (score 1):

For OSX you'd have to use the DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES env. variable instead of LD_PRELOAD.

However I'm fairly certain you won't get the overriding to work. The closest thing I can find is you'll have to do some magic assembly tricks, which someone has neatly packaged up in the code under mach_override here: http://extendamac.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/extendamac/trunk/code/

Comment: Hi :-) Really? Is that complicated under mac os x? I have downloaded mach_override and I am studying the source code but I don't understand how to use it yet. The package does not contain text documentation :P Thank you anyway. Any examples of use are welcomed :P