# How to hook all operating system calls of my own process?

Tags: windows, api, macos, hook

I need to hijack all operating system calls of my own process. I cannot rewrite code as it is partly not my code (plug-ins). I need to be able to decide within my implementation of a specific system call, if I want to call the original implementation or not.

Operating systems will be at first windows xp and higher versions. Later os x 10.5 and higher will follow. Starting on windows with 32 bit versions, later for all operating systems also 64 bit versions.

I found a lot of documentation and tools about hooking other processes but I would hope my job is much simpler and I would hope for some source code.

Thanks a lot in advance, Bernd.

Comment: Frankly, *all* system calls is a lot. The best would perhaps be to write a loadable kernel module in which you hook every single syscall there is. In my opinion an approach covering only the system calls relevant to your problem would be a smarter move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many hooking libraries that will let you do this, for example Detours or madCodeHook on Windows. No doubt there are similar libraries on OSX, I just don't know them!

It's very easy to hook a routine and replace it with your own implementation.  It's less easy to retain the option of running the original routine in some circumstances, and that's where using a hooking library will take the pain away for you.

Comment: When choosing a hooking library, or implementing one yourself, make sure it is thread safe!

Comment: Thanks. At first I thought, yah, I know these libraries. But actually your answer inspired me to rethink and now I see a way to actually use one of these libraries. So, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X, you can override functions with the [`DYLD_INTERPOSE`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-97.1/include/mach-o/dyld-interposing.h) macro (and [`DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html), if needed). This answer has an example: [Ansi C patch using dlsym compiles OK under linux but fails on Mac Os X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810326/ansi-c-patch-using-dlsym-compiles-ok-under-linux-but-fails-on-mac-os-x/3816802#3816802)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, there is the open source alternative to [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) called EasyHook:

- [CodePlex: EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/)
- [Code Project: EasyHook - The reinvention of Windows API hooking](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking)