# Forbid program that is running with administrator privileges to access the list of running processes

Tags: windows, limit, administrator, terminal-services, rights

I have an application on a wts that has to run with administrator privileges. It checks for running instances of Internet Explorer and does not start if it finds that there is an instance of IE running (because it will spawn it's on IE instance).

So if any other user on the same terminal server is also working with IE, this application won't start.

Is there any way to trick this application, so that it can't access the current running processes list? Or receives a fake one? I'd prefer free & open source solutions. I am also a .NET developer myself, so I could write some starter if that is required. I'm a bit lost, because I never had to worry about such access

Thanks for your time!

Comment: When you say "I have an application" do you mean it is an application you've got the source code for?  Because the proper solution is to fix the application, not to try to trick it.

Comment: We do not have the source code, we can only execute it. The problem is, that you can't rename the Internet Explorer 8 executable, because it won't run with any other name.

Edit: (We can not use any other Version of IE either)

Comment: You could do this with API hooking, but it's not easy.  See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090685/how-to-hook-all-operating-system-calls-of-my-own-process